# What was the extent of Japanese control after the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs and before surrender?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, maps

What was the extent of Japanese control after the atomic bombings of Hiroshima and Nagasaki? I am talking about before their surrender. A map would be **extremely** preferred for better understanding.

Comment: Japanese control of what?

Comment: I wonder if you done any previous research on this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://omniatlas.com/maps/eastasia/19450815/ has a map that shows the Empire of Japan. It was very big even during the surrender.

[image]

Comment: +1. This was a good find, but more commentary would have made your answer better.

Comment: My sense is that despite how much territory was under Japanese control, they did not have fuel, ammo or food in sufficient quantities to continue to hold.

Comment: Note that at the time of surrender it was shrinking *very* rapidly as the Soviets devoured Manchuria in a matter of weeks.

Answer (score 7):

I am adding a [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBemh.png) of 1942, to show Japan's maximum extent, to contrast with the excellent map put up by Sadiq.

Compared with 1942, Japan had lost most of Burma to the British, and most of Manchuria to the Russians. The Americans had recaptured the Philippines, and numerous Pacific islands. But Japan had maintained her home territory (except for Iwo Jima and Okinawa) and even increased her holdings in China, holding onto Vietnam, Laos, and Cambodia in Indochina.

[cbi-theater.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=japanese+empire+1942&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS686US687&espv=2&biw=1517&bih=735&tbm=isch&imgil=CqMmUcyFafSIgM%253A%253Bg18cFb4ID80vjM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.cbi-theater.com%25252Fmaps%25252Fmap005.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=CqMmUcyFafSIgM%253A%252Cg18cFb4ID80vjM%252C_&usg=__pfoVQ3vBjSsvUze8X1xyKUuxbjQ%3D&dpr=0.9&ved=0ahUKEwjb6Y204tfQAhWJhlQKHUIHD78QyjcINA&ei=LJhCWNujOImN0gLCjrz4Cw#imgrc=CqMmUcyFafSIgM%3A/) has a map that shows the Empire of Japan in 1942.

[image: Empire of Japan in 1942]